Inconsitent Error when using Dapper and SqlIte
I am struggling with a System.BadImageFormatException: The signature is incorrect exception when making the below call. I've confirmed that the DB types are all correct, and the naming is case correct.
Project Info:

.NET Framework -> 4.8
Dapper -> 2.1.35
System.Data.SQLite -> 1.0.119
CPU -> x64

using (cnn)
{
    cnn.Open();
   
    IEnumerable<TestyBoy> test = cnn.Query<TestyBoy>($"SELECT creature.id FROM creature WHERE creature.map = 1;");

    cnn.Close();
}

public class TestyBoy
{
    public TestyBoy() {}
    public int id { get; set; }
}

I've confirmed that the fields in the SQLite DB match correctly in name and type.
It may be noteworthy that a simpler call works fine and is stable:
var ids = cnn.Query<int>("SELECT Creature.ID FROM Creature LIMIT 100;");

I've confirmed that my project is targeting x64 in every setting I can find.
I've also tried various changes to (in this case) the TestBoy class and non of them seem to change the expection at all.
Full expection :

!
System.BadImageFormatException: The signature is incorrect.
at System.Delegate.BindToMethodInfo(Object target, IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType methodType, DelegateBindingFlags flags)
at System.Delegate.CreateDelegateNoSecurityCheck(Type type, Object target, RuntimeMethodHandle method)
at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetTypeDeserializerImpl(Type type, DbDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in //Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 3270
at Dapper.SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.GetReader(DbDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in //Dapper/SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.cs:line 151
at Dapper.SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.GetReader(Type type, DbDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in //Dapper/SqlMapper.TypeDeserializerCache.cs:line 50
at Dapper.SqlMapper.GetDeserializer(Type type, DbDataReader reader, Int32 startBound, Int32 length, Boolean returnNullIfFirstMissing) in //Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1917
at Dapper.SqlMapper.d__1441.MoveNext() in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1172 at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable1 commandTimeout, Nullable1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 801
!

Call stack
Calling the ADO directly seems to work just fine :
using (var cmd = new SqliteCommand("SELECT creature.id FROM creature WHERE creature.map = 1;", cnn))
{
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);  
            Console.WriteLine($"{id}");
        }
    }
}


I'm not aware of any known issue here; if you can find a reliable repro: I'm very interested. However, in mitigation: have you tried enabling Dapper's AOT mode? That should side-step the offending delegate creation: https://aot.dapperlib.dev/gettingstarted.html (for context: I'm basically Dapper)

The error complains about a bad DLL, not Dapper. Microsoft's SQLite Nuget is Microsoft.Data.Sqltie, not System.Data.Sqlite. It's quite possible the wrong native package was copied to bin. Switch to Microsoft's SQLite driver and check if you get any error there

@PanagiotisKanavos yes, that was my hunch too - if Dapper was borking, I'd expect InvalidProgramException, not BadImageFormatException; my hunch here is that Dapper's reflection/discovery is causing an external type to be loaded during IL-compile, and that type is coming from a dll that is bad - and yes, the most likely meaning of "bad" there is the wrong CPU architecture or target OS of an unmanaged dll. For the CPU architecture aspect, I'd strongly suggest turning off AnyCPU if enabled, preferring explicit CPU targets (when using unmanaged, CPU-specific, dlls)

I'd switch to Microsoft.Data.Sqlite anyway - one is actively supported by ErikEJ and Microsoft, the other only occasionally gets a release from the SQLite team - once or twice a year.

Thank you for the responses. @MarcGravell ,Panagiotis Kanavos.
I've swapped out System.Data.Sqlite for the Mircrosoft version. I have also enabled and installed Dapper.AOT and added the [module: DapperAot] to my namespace after doing a clean and rebuild I still get the exact same error. The CPU target is set to  x64.

@CameronConnellan OK; have you tried using ADO.NET directly, i.e. new SqliteCommand(...) etc? if that doesn't work, Dapper doesn't stand a chance

@MarcGravell
using (var cmd = new SqliteCommand("SELECT creature.id FROM creature WHERE creature.map = 1;", cnn))
{
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);  
            Console.WriteLine($"{id}");
        }
    }
}

And it works great.

I'd also strongly suspect the using is wrong, or otherwise the DLL is incorrect., perhaps 32 vs 64 bit.

@CameronConnellan this seems very weird; I certainly haven't seen anything like that in integration tests etc; is there some minimal repro of this? perhaps as a GitHub project I can download and run to see what you're seeing?
